# Create internationalized properties under maven directory "test/resources" is a bad idea?

Tags: maven, junit, internationalization, properties-file

In order to tests our internationalized messages returned by our spring application, in our junit tests we usually create under maven directory "test/resources" the "messages.properties" copied from the "main/resources" directory. I think this is a bad idea because your test is not really checking the properties that will be used in runtime that are the ones present under the "main/resources" directory. Is this a bad practice?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you copy it? If you have already one in `src/main/resources` it is available on the classpath which means also during the test?

Comment: To me it had no sense too. Thanks